# How to fix - `ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed`

Tags: karate

1. I've connect mongoDb with SSL & Certs(Trust, Keystore) using Springboot

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStoreFilePath.getPath());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", truststorePassword);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStoreFilePath.getPath());
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keystorePassword);
```

2. Then, able to connect successfully
3. Then, tried REST call on `https://xxxxxx.net/api/v1/login`

Added and tried below options
- karate.configure('ssl', true);
- * configure ssl = true

i'm getting below error -

```
admin_login.feature
21:43:28.106 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target, http call failed after 943 milliseconds for URL: https://xxxxxx.net/api/v1/login
21:43:28.107 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
21:43:28.114 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - feature call failed: classpath:admin_login.feature
arg: [object Object]
admin_login.feature:8 - 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
21:43:28.116 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - javascript function call failed: 
admin_login.feature:8 - 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

4. if i'm not connecting db with ssl. able to call all REST calls
   Please help on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL can be tricky, you may need time and patience.

Normally `* configure ssl = true` should just work in Karate because it will disable certificate validation. Sounds like here you have set some System properties that is being picked up by Karate also. Refer https://github.com/intuit/karate#system-properties-for-ssl-and-http-proxy

So maybe if you use the [advanced form of `configure ssl`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#x509-certificate-authentication) you can get it it work.

Remember if are still stuck and you need more support, follow the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: i've tried many ways, but not useful. good to have an issue for more analysis on this fix.