# KarateUI: How to Handle SSL Certificate during geckodriver configuration?

Tags: karate

Please, provide the solution for accepting insecure certificates during **geckodriver** configuration. 
Is it possible to add `{"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"acceptInsecureCerts": true}}}` into addOptions ?

I tried, but it does not help, even browser instance is not created.

```
        var driverConfig = {
            type: 'geckodriver',
            showDriverLog: true,
            addOptions:["'capabilities': {'alwaysMatch': {'acceptInsecureCerts': true}}"]
        };
        karate.configure('driver', driverConfig);
```

Comment: Please check if the following answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57126580/how-to-fix-error-com-intuit-karate-http-request-failed

Comment: Thanks, but it did not help.

Comment: @Svitlana we are working on this see: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/924#issuecomment-578382382